# Otsu method (graythresh function in matlab) produces a scaled result on which scale? 0:255, 0:max(px intensity), min:max?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, grayscale, edge-detection

Just clarifying a point about the Otsu thresholding method that lacks definition in the documentation & wikipedia articles. If you apply the Otsu method (in matlab the function `graythresh`) it returns a threshold value between 0 and 1.

Given 2 hypothetical grayscale images:

- `dark` (with pixel intensities in the range of 0 to 100) and
- `light` (with pixel intensities in the range of 155 to 255)

If I got an Otsu threshold of 0.75 for both `dark` and `light` images respectively, what grayscale pixel intensity would it map to in each case?

- `dark ->  75` and `light -> 231` E.g. relative to the range of values in each image
- `dark ->  75` and `light -> 191` E.g. relative to the range 0 to max pixel value
- `dark -> 191` and `light -> 191` E.g. relative to the full range of grayscale pixel values (0-255)?

Comment: Hmm, now we've got some dissenting answers. I've unset the question as answered, anyone else want to weigh in?

Comment: Ratbert's answer is correct. You should mark his as accepted.  The 0.75 is with respect to the dynamic range of your grayscale images. You can verify this by looking at the source of `graythresh` by doing `open graythresh` in the MATLAB command prompt.  For the dark images, 0.75 is 75% of the way between 0 - 100, and so 75 is the answer.  For the light image, 75% of the way is `155 + (255-155)*0.75 ~ 230`.... I upvoted Ratbert's answer.

Comment: I've read all of these answers, but I'm not convinced @Ratbert is correct. If `graythresh` returned a value relative to the range of its input, why would `a = graythresh(uint8([10 20]))` return a different value than `b = graythresh(uint8([20 30]))`? Look at what Ratbert suggests the threshold of `a` is: `a * (20 - 10) + 10`, which is `10.5686`, whereas Anand suggests that the threshold is `a * 255`, which is `14.5`. The second calculation makes a _lot_ more sense!

Comment: It's been a while since I looked into this, and to provide more concrete evidence for or against Anand I'm going to have to devote some more time to it (which I'd like to). I haven't been able to do so yet, if anyone else with interest wants to do some follow up investigative work and weight in it'll be most welcome. My intuition still is that Ratbert's answer is right, which my original follow up seemed to support. But to argue it further requires more effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer is the first one :

dark = 75 and light = 230, relative to the range of values in each image

`graythresh` uses the min and max values in the image as boundaries, which is the most logical behavior.

Comment: Just to precise my thoughts: the first solution is the only logical one, because of the algorithm itself: Otsu's method is about minimizing the intra class variance of the black and white regions. There is no reason why the result should depend on some arbitrary fixed boundaries. It should work with any real vector in fact, including negative or arbitrary high values etc.

Comment: Bonjour! I can't remember if I told you this... but just in case, I've made a MATLAB chat room for us in case you wanted to discuss anything related to MATLAB that is off-topic, or if you want to discuss things that span longer than a comments block.  Stop by when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Comment: Thanks a lot rayryeng, that's very nice.

Comment: Anand's answer is correct as I explained below. This accepted answer is wrong and misleading. Anand gives compelling examples. Looking at the MATLAB source code makes this even clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer by @Ratbert makes the incorrect claims that

> The correct answer is the first one

and

> `graythresh` uses the min and max values in the image as boundaries,
>   which is the most logical behavior.

and rayryeng appears to agree with it. David Parks appears to have empirically verified it.

The correct answer is given by Anand which strangely seems to have a negative vote. He explains very convincingly that

> full range of grayscale pixel values' depends on the **data type** of the input image

As he explains,

> this is the third option

except for the fact that the `dark` image could not possibly get a threshold of 0.75.

First let us clarify the difference between the claims for the simplest case, in clear MATLAB, so there is no confusion. For an image with values ranging from `min` to `max`, the question poses three possibilities which, when translated to an equation are:

1. `threshold = min + (max-min) * graythresh`
2. `threshold = max * graythresh`
3. `threshold = 255 * graythresh`

Suppose the image consists of just two points one with an intensity of 0, and the other with 100. This means `dark = uint8([0 100]);`. A second image `light = dark+155;`. When we compute `255*graythresh(dark)` we get exactly `49.5`. When we compute `255*graythresh(light)` we get exactly `204.5`. These answers make it patently obvious that the third option is the only possibility.

There is one further fine point. If you try `255*graythresh(uint8(1:2))` the answer is `1`, and not `1.5`. So it appears that if you are using `greythresh` to threshold an image, you should use `image <= 255*graythesh(image)` with a *less-than-or-equal-to*, rather than a plain *less-than*.

Comment: Hi there, I appreciate the addition to this, but I'm not quite convinced by your argument though. I think this is a counterexample to your argument, try these 3 statements in matlab: `graythresh(uint8([0 0 128 255]))`  `graythresh(uint8([0 128 255]))`  `graythresh(uint8([128 255]))`.  Clearly the 0's don't have an effect because the first 2 statements return 0.2490, in fact any number of 0's yield this value. Showing that the value of 0 affects the range it's calculated over, but not the result. However, when the 0 is removed the result changes (0.7490) due to the range being 128 to 255 only.

Comment: I don't see how this is a counterexample to what I said. graythesh tries to break the numbers into two sets. It then outputs the point which splits the two sets. If the sets are separated, it outputs the midpoint. In the first two examples, the two sets are {0} and {128,255}. So the output is midpoint between 0 and 128 which it take to be 63.5/255 = 0.2490. In the third case the two groups are {128} and {255} which is given a midpoint of 191/255 = 0.7490. In all cases the division is being done by 255 (which is the 3rd option in the question). Note `graythresh(uint8([0 127 255]))*255 = 190.5`.

Comment: In fact the simple fact that multiplying the output of `graythresh` by 255 *always* results in an integer or an integer and a half, establishes the fact that the divisor is *always* 255, which is what the questions is about. A counterexample would show number from `graythresh` that is a fraction with some other number in the denominator. That would shut me up completely.

Answer (score 2):

Your third answer seems most right to me, with the clarification that 'full range of grayscale pixel values' depends on the data type of the input image. For example, for a uint8 image, an Otsu threshold of 0.75 corresponds to around 191. For a uint16 image, this would correspond to 49151.

Comment: If you look at the source code for graythresh, it first converts the image to uint8 and uses imhist to compute a 256 bin image histogram before computing the actual otsu threshold. The normalization later happens using the following code : `level = (idx-1) / (num_bins-1);`. Working backward from this helps drive my point. When `level` is 0, the first bin of the histogram is where the threshold lies. For a 256 bin uint8 histogram, that means 0. When the `level` is 1, this corresponds to 255.

Comment: If the returned level depended on dynamic range of the data and not the type, the following two would return the same answer, but don't. `graythresh(uint8(10:20))` and `graythresh(uint8(40:50))`.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. It is obvious that the result of your two commands _have to_ be different. And this is exactly what I said previously.

Comment: As I understand it, your hypothesis is that the number returned by graythresh is scaled using the dynamic range of image pixels in the image (I may have totally botched that, so apologies in advance). So, the distribution of data for the first image (`uint8(10:20)`) and the second image (`uint8(40:50)`) are the same. Hence, the scaled result of `graythresh` should be the same if your hypothesis holds true. In either case, the comment above that explains why I'm certain that the range of the input class ([0-255] for uint8, [0-65535] for uint16 etc.) not the dynamic range of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for posterity sake I did a comparison of the approaches mentioned before. I took a typical image with a full range of grayscale pixel intensities, then took a `dark` and `light` version of the same image and got the `graythresh` value for each. I Applied the Otsu threshold using each of the above mappings.

The light image pretty clearly demonstrates that the algorithm is producing a threshold over the range of the images' pixel intensities. Were we to assume a full range of pixel intensities, the Otsu algorithm would be producing a threshold below any actually present in the image, which doesn't make much sense, at least presuming the existing black background is transparent/irrelevant.

I suppose someone could make an argument for assuming the full range of pixel intensities if you assume the existing black part of the image were relevant darkness. I would certainly welcome comments there.

[Full size images seen below](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1X5CyLVSwU36trbqgP87e_OtY1oZY4QNxBxzGDx5XPW4/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Comparison of grayscale intensity obtained from OTSU threshold]

---

Amending my words above: When I blacken all but the top half of the `light` image and take the Otsu threshold again I get the same threshold value of 0.3020. Were the dark parts of the image relevant to the Otsu threshold being produced the extra darkness would have affected the value, therefore, Ratbert's answer is empirically demonstrated as correct.

[image: Further test]